# Removing LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList policy from Google Chrome on macOS

Tags: google-chrome, plist

I was able to add a policy using,

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList -array-add "\"[*.]mydomain.com"\"
```

This got reflected correctly on the *com.google.Chrome.plist* (also in chrome://policy/ for chrome-based chrome, edge and brave browsers)and I was able to fulfil my requirement by changing SameSite behavior for cookies on mydomain.com

But when I try to delete this policy using,

```
defaults delete LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList
```

I was able to remove it from the com.google.Chrome.plist but the policy is still appearing within *chrome://policy/* I have already tried restarting Chrome, reloading policies etc.. with no luck. Any clue?

On a separate note, I was able to add and remove ***LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled*** policy without any issues. But I wanted to use ***LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList*** policy so I can specify the exact domain rather enabling this behavior globally.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue with delete, This was registered in Apple's domain by default for some reason.(I might have mistakenly run without the domain)

With the following I was able to solve the issue

```
defaults delete "Apple Global Domain" LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList
```